# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER | Selenium-wire Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I am trying to visit a website and get the website's network headers. However, I'm getting this error "SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER"

There's no "Accept the Risk and Continue" option. Only go back.

I've tried just about everything I could find about this and none of them worked.

Code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'path\to\profile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("url")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused this, could be an extension or something but I just created a new Firefox profile and it worked.